# Displaying a Favicon using recommended code is not working

Tags: html, favicon

I have "Googled" this quite a bit in the past hour.

I am working on a new website, and I've never used favicons before (I always forget about them). So, the first place I looked was Google, and the first result that came up was this one:

[How To Add A Favicon To Your Site (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

And after trying out the first two options, and re-uploading the files to the server I have found that neither of the snippets of code on that page listed above work for me. I have double-checked that all references to the favicon are correct and that all files are in the right places. I have even tried using a *.PNG file instead of an actual icon (*.ico), which I have seen in use on other sites.

Then, I went back to Google and looked at a few more sites, and tried the code in those tutorials. It worked! Well, kind of... It worked in Flock web browser, FireFox, and Chrome. But it didn't work in Internet Explorer 9, 8, 7, or 6.

I then came over here to S/O, and "View Source"'d the homepage and used their favicon code and that still didn't work!

Here's the latest piece of code that I have now:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mywebsite.com/favicon.ico">
```

What is the most reliable way of ensuring my Favicon displays in every browser?

### Updates

---

1. Tried Bookmarking the page - Didn't work.

Comment: did you try bookmarking the site?  some browsers only show the favicon on bookmarked sites.  And is it EXACTLY 16x16 or 32x32?

Comment: @cwolves: It is exactly 16 x 16px. No I didn't originally try to Bookmark the site as I didn't know that. But I just tried it after reading your comment and then I refreshed the page after bookmarking it. Didn't work.

Comment: Maybe a caching problem? FFox3 sometimes took a while to recognize a changed favico. Check if your server logs show a request for the icon is served.

Comment: Thank you @Ulright S - I will check the server logs now. But I did also clear the cache for that domain using I.E 9 Developer Tools (F12), which didn't have any effect.

Comment: @Ulright: I just tried to view my server logs but my host isn't letting me access the httplogs directory. I'm not even sure it was created when I enabled Raw Logging because I've never been able to find logs.

Comment: Okay, this is truely wierd. I just refreshed the url http://mydomainexample.com/favicon.ico and it is now displaying the Favicon in the Address Bar and the Tab. But, if I browse to any PHP or HTML page of my site - it still won't display at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favicons are really annoying to recieve because they cache. Try using another computer and navigating to domain.com/favico.(png/ico)

Comment: Done. Thank you @Craig. I navigated to mysite/favicon.ico and the icon displayed as content in the page. So it's definitely there, and the browser can access it. It just won't display it in the Tab or Address Bar section. And it works in every other browser, just not I.E.

Comment: IE is a pain beyond compare. Just hope that it works. if not dont worry, it doesn't always show often anyway on most sites. Also, please mark this as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Yup. I.E is my worst enemy. But for some unknown reason I would rather burn myself alive than use any other browser (Except maybe Flock, I love Flock's Favorite system. So cool.) Ofcourse! I'll accept, when the timer will let me. I also tried to up-vote you but I need 15 more reputation to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions to your .ico/.png file.
I had the same problem once. So I went to `http://my-url/my-favicon.ico` and I got "Permission Denied" error.

I did chmod 644 to my-favicon.ico and it worked. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
```

[For more detail about favicon please check](http://www.getallcodes.in/html-html-5/favicon-html-code.html)

Comment: The question had almost exactly the same code in it.